# log exceeded limit of 4194304 bytes on Gitlab

Tags: gitlab, aem, gitlab-ci-runner

I am running a job in gitlab to upload AEM package through curl command but on trying with a big package, I am getting error "log exceeded limit of 4194304 bytes". I cannot break the job into multiple jobs, please help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gitlab CI/CD job's log exceeded limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53541000/gitlab-ci-cd-jobs-log-exceeded-limit)

Comment: I am unable to locate this file. Can you help more on this?

Comment: the file is `config.toml`. The location depends of your running system, check the [documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/advanced-configuration.html)

Comment: I tried setting output_limit = "40000" in the runners section of config.toml but still the error is coming. I have read multiple posts but this hadn't helped many.

Comment: Did you restart your runner ? Could you edit the post with the `[[runner]]` section config ?

Comment: Did you try curl --silent http://www.example.com/ > /dev/null ?

Answer (score 0):

The default value of gitlab-runner output log is 4096 Kilobytes.

Update the default value by overriding it here:

https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/charts/gitlab-runner/-/blob/main/values.yaml#L390

```sh
outputLimit: 8192
```