# gitlab-runner log size exceeded

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, git-log

I am using ranchar2 gitlab runner and don't have control over it's configuration
but while running tests I am getting Job's log exceeded limit of 4194304 bytes error .

Is there any way I can change runner setting's from ci.yml file ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Gitlab CI/CD job's log exceeded limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53541000/gitlab-ci-cd-jobs-log-exceeded-limit)