# How to configure output limit of gitlab CI job log on the web interface?

Tags: gitlab, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, gitlab-ce

The output limit of a job log is truncated at 500KiB. How can I increase that?

`output_limit` in the `config.toml` did not seem to change that. I think that is something different.

The problem as shown in an image:

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Gitlab CI/CD job's log exceeded limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53541000/gitlab-ci-cd-jobs-log-exceeded-limit)

Comment: Just wondering if you restarted the gitlab runner after changing the `output_limit`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not currently possible to change the truncation limit for the runner log viewer. There is an open issue requesting this: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/295654

The runner `output_limit` in `config.toml` is [documented](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/advanced-configuration.html#the-runners-section) as:

> Maximum build log size in kilobytes. Default is 4096 (4MB).

Jobs that exceed the runner limit continue to run, but the log is truncated when it hits the limit, i.e. the log data is lost.

GitLab also has an instance limit on job logs. If this is hit then the job will be killed.

> The job log file size limit in GitLab is 100 megabytes by default. Any job that exceeds the limit is marked as failed, and dropped by the runner.

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/instance_limits.html#maximum-file-size-for-job-logs